# Why "?:" operator cannot return list?

Tags: perl, perlop

Why `?:` operator can not return list?

```
my $hash =  {
    ...
    ($row->active?checked=>1:()),
};
```

The [DOC](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator) say nothing about scalar or list context

**UPD**
Another example:

```
@list =  2,3;         # CORRECT
@list =  1? 2,3 : (); # Syntax error
```

Why first is OK, but second is not? It seems there should not be the problem for perl to just propagate `2,3` to the outer context;

Comment: Are you getting some sort of error?  What exactly is `checked=>1` supposed to be?  That's not a value that I recognize.

Comment: @hymie: 1. I get syntax error. 2. `checked => 1` It is the list: `'checked',1`

Comment: `@list =  2,3;` may be correct **syntax**, but did you check to see what the resulting list actually contains?

Comment: `checked=>1` is not a list.  `(checked => 1)` is a hash.  The parentheses are part of the syntax, not an option to be ignored.

Comment: @hymie: `( checked => 1 )` is *not* a hash: it's a list of two values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `,` and `=>` (the list separators) have lower precedence than `?:`  and `=`.

So it's not a question about whether perl is passing the right hand side of `=` as a list or scalar. It's a syntax error because `@list=1?2` and `3:()` are handled as separate items of a list, each containing half a `?:` statement which is not allowed.

Answer (score 7):

This has nothing to do with context. You need to put parenthesis around the middle part for Perl to properly parse your syntax.

```
my $hash = { ( 1 ? ( checked => 1 ) : () ), };
```

Without those, there is a syntax error.

> syntax error at /home/simbabque/code/scratch/scratch.pl line 109, near "checked =>"

Comment: I know how to fix the problem. The question is why perl can not paththrough the `checked => 1` to the outer context. It seems to be correct

Comment: @EugenKonkov "It seems to be correct"  It isn't.  `perl` has a syntax specification that it expects you to follow.

Comment: hymie: I thought that only perl 6 has syntax specification... May you please point me to the specification for perl 5?

Comment: @EugenKonkov Sure -- `perldoc perldata`

Comment: @hymie: There is nothing about ternary operator